# Display Colab notebook with hidden cells on Github

Tags: github, markdown, google-colaboratory

I have a google colab notebook where I use

```
# @title 1.1) suggested solution
```

to hide a block of code. In colab hidden cells work as expected, but when I push the notebook to Github, the hidden cells show like this

```
# @title 1.1) suggested solution fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,4)) plt.title('Time series data') plt.xlabel('Days') plt.ylabel('y') plt.plot(y) plt.show()
```

Is there any way to make the hidden cells in colab also hidden in Github?